# Can't find android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, android-support-library

gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

app/build.gradle:

def AAVersion = '4.6.0'

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.0@aar') { transitive = true; }
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
```

but I get compile error in my activity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

error:

```
package android.support.v7.app does not exist
```

Comment: have you tried removing your support-v7 dependency and adding it again ?

Comment: @Alex Yes this is correct as you're using AndroidX to use "ActionBarDrawerToggle". You have to use  following 
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'

Comment: @Umair yes, but it not help

Comment: @yash786 not help. I get same error